# instalacion sass con comando npm install -g sass da error

Tags: sass, instalacion

Estoy queriendo instalar sass en mi mac y me da error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
MacBook-Air-de-Gonzalo:clase_sass c.gonzalo12$ npm install -g sass
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/c.gonzalo12/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/sass
npm ERR! dest /Users/c.gonzalo12/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.sass-FDnUqOu1
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/c.gonzalo12/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/c.gonzalo12/.npm/_logs/2023-07-17T20_26_13_252Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Buenas! Por favor agrega el error como texto.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del error dice:

```
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/c.gonzalo12/.npm"
```

Extrayendo información relevante del error y traduciendo al buen español:

```
Para solucionar permanentemente este problema, ejecuta: 
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/c.gonzalo12/.npm"
```

Por otro lado, cuando vayas a ejecutar cosas del npm en Mac y distros linuxeras, se sugiere hacerlo con los permisos necesarios, algunos son extremos y le dan siempre permisos de root (sudo su...).

PD: En el remoto caso que luego de ejecutar ese comando, todo siga igual, reinicia la applicación y/o la terminal.